# Forcing Windows Store apps to install on a non-system disk in Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, windows-store

I am trying to force Windows Store apps to install on a non-system disk E.
I have modified the following registry setting in Windows 8.1 x64:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx`

namely the key `PackageRoot` to `E:\WindowsApps`.

I have found multiple [suggestions to do this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-install-location-windows-8-store-apps) on the web.

But now when I try to install any Windows Store app I get `0xd00000bb` error. It seems it is not working on Windows 8.1.

I have found [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc025f33-ec85-410b-be50-db97074fe409/windows-store-error-code-0xd00000bb?forum=w8itproinstall), but it offers no real solution to the problem.
There are [some hints how to do it here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/error-0xd00002b8/b0c49334-5ae8-454c-be39-c9f13e7725d0), but the steps to take are not very well documented.

**What should I do to resolve this problem and force Windows 8.1 apps to be installed on a non-system drive?**

---

I have fixed 0xd00000bb error, by adding `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` full control to  `E:\WindowsApps`. But all the preinstalled windows store apps stopped working, just initial screen and then nothing (Unable to start a Dcom Server: AppexMaps ...).

---

After several hours of meddling with registry, folders permissions and symlinks I have put things back to standard on C and it is working again. Unable to find a working solution.

Comment: What you want to do is not supported so by soon so you can expect it to not only be tough to do but also present problems in the future even including breaking functionality

Comment: Yes, but I have expected something else given that on Windows Phone 8.1 there is a very simple setting allowing exactly this.

Comment: Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8 while similar are very different currently

Comment: Indeed @VojtěchDohnal, going to Program Files\WindowsApp -> Right Click -> Properties -> Security: I set owner to Myself, deleted 'Users' from the contro list and gave full control to 'Administrator' and 'Trusted installer' and made unchecked "Only Read" flag from folder. Problem solved in my Junction partitions! :D

Answer (score 0):

I added `*\Users` to a list of users for `E:\WindowsApps` folder and now no error is popping out for me.

Comment: I will update to 10 very soon, so I will not try it, I would only MS official solution.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal will windows 10 have a possibility to change the install path? would be nice if it will

Comment: looks hopefully - see http://www.thewindowsclub.com/move-windows-10-apps-other-drive-change-install-location

Comment: what do you mean/ how did you do to ADD *\users ?